# CSS style not applied - Depot from Agile Web Development With Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass

I'm struggling with this for several hours now, tried all solutions i found, and no luck. Still, my first try to run Depot example from book is running without any CSS applied.

I'm sure scss is compiled, as chrome shows me that application.css, scaffolds.css and products.css loaded. I tried to create other css file - not scss - but with only partial luck, only some of styling was applied - rest is matched with user agent stylesheet and inherits some of scaffolds.css properties - but not important ones.

I'm loading all css in application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

and in same file i'm declaring class for :

```
<body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
```

table from products/index.html.rb is nothing unusual:

```
<table>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
    <td><%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image') %></td>
    <td class="list_description">
      <dl>
        <dt><%= product.title %></dt>
        <dd><%= truncate( strip_tags( product.description ), lenght: 80) %></dd>
      </dl>
    </td>
    <td class="list_actions">
      <%= link_to 'Show', product %><br/>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %><br/>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', product, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

and products.scss (i tried renaming from .css.scss, but no change)

```
    .products {

    ​  table {
        border-collapse:  collapse;
      }
      ​
      table tr td {
        padding:5px;
        vertical-align:top;
      }
      ​
      .list_image {
        width:60px;
        height:70px;
      }
      ​
      .list_description {
        width:60%;
        ​
        dl {
          margin:0;
        }
        ​
        dt {
          color: #244;
          font-weight:bold;
          font-size:larger;
        }

        dd {
          margin:0;
        }
      }

    ​  .list_actions {
        font-size:x-small;
        text-align:right;
        padding-left:1em;
      }

    ​  .list_line_even {
        background: #e0f8f8;
      }

    ​  .list_line_odd {
        background: #f8b0f8;
      }
}
```

and my application.css looks like this:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

And apparently, something is wrong.I'm running on Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3. Ruby on Rails is new to me, but i feel strong urge to learn something (and i've some time to learn - might not happen in next few months) but when i'm stuck like this i lose time, and learn nothing - or almost nothing - new :)

If it was answered and i happened not to find proper answer, big apology, just point me in right direction and give thruster kick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've started to work it out. CSS validator shown that there are errors:

> Encountered: "\u200b" (8203), after : ""

so now i'm putting code by hand, character after character without copy/paste from the book. It looks like it's working after removing tmp/cache and public/application.css

Answer (score 1):

it should be products.css.scss not products.scss under /app/assets/stylesheets/

As I look into your example table put a div tag with class="products" above your table.

```
<div class="products">
  <table>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as i know, it's no difference if file is named .css or .css.scss - but of course tried with both.

Also - as you can see, class "products" is used for <body> tag. Also i tried to do it without nesting styling - put just css for all elements regardless of parent tag, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The table declaration needs the class, so in the index file it should be

```html
<table class ="products">
```

Neither the book nor the downloadable file have it that way, but digging through the errata yielded the answer. https://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/errata

Comment: The selector that will be generated is `.products table`, adding the class to the table element will not work here (also, someone already gave that answer well before you).

Comment: It does work here. Without it it doesn't, at least at this point in the book. So anyone working through the book and finding this question will be frustrated without it. I found the answer in the errata, in a post written by the book's author, which I mentioned. And the other answer wrapped it in a div, which unnecessarily complicates it.